# selection vertices by user's value

Tags: selection-tools

I have a mesh (like a city mesh) referenced to the origin (X=0,Y=0,Z=0) and i'd like to select all vertices with value Z=237 (i'd say to the computer) and X=129 (i'd say to the computer) Y=any, for example (is like select the thirds floor from all buildings). How could i do that.
PD: Or edges , or faces, or from several objects

Comment: @MrZak I think the OP is referring to a large model where it would be difficult to eyeball the correct selection range in the viewport, so he would like to use some kind of numerical input to define the boundaries of the selection box.

Comment: Ok Carlo. The example is clear, all vertices with X=129, Y=any, Z=237 in a big city mesh.